# Add shortcut to :term in vim <C-`>

Tags: windows, vim, backticks

I recently discovered vim has `:term` command to open terminal inside vim. I want to create a keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> just like in visual studio code. But `` :map <C-`> :term `` doesn't do anything.
Can anybody help. I am on windows using gvim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: You cannot use this key combination; choose another one.**

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The problem is that <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> won't be treated as a different key.

Only `@`, `A-Z`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^` and `_` map to ASCII characters (0 through 31 respectively) when combined with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>

To check this, You can try the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>

It'll print ` itself.

You'll have to find some other key combination for this.